# How to use addEventListener to redirect to another html page on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

How to redirect to the next page using addEventListner?

Here, when I click the button it has to redirect to another HTML page
how to write the code for that.

HTML

```
<button>submit</button>
```

JS

```
let btn = document.querySelector('button')
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Comment: `window.location.href = "http://www.myurl.com";` inside your eventListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
let btn = document.querySelector('button')
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    window.location.replace('http://www.example.com');
})
```